# How to set up navigation view with condition?

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton, android-navigationview

I have two navigation view for both side in android. As shown in the link image below, left side for user who signup as a parents meanwhile the right side for the user who signup as a tuition provider. For example, if User A sign up as a parents, so he/she can only open the left side navigation only. What coding should I write to make sure that he/she is the user for each navigation view. Can someone help or teach me please?

EXAMPLE OF MY INTERFACE

[image]

Im trying this coding:-

```
userCategory = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.user_radio_group_btn);
    Integer checkedID = userCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedID);
    String selection = radioButton.getText().toString();

    if (selection.equals("Parents"))
    {
        menuRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tuitionProvider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (selection.equals("Tuition Provider"))
    {
        menuLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        parents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    else
    {
        Intent RegistrationIntent = new Intent(home.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(RegistrationIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please register first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

XML CODING:-

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/user_radio_group_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/parents_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="Parents" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/tuition_provider_radio_button"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="Tuition Provider" />
</RadioGroup>
```

ERROR I GOT

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.home.onCreate(home.java:59)

Comment: Its clearly mention in your ERROR Log to your home.java file with line number 59 which something has null.

Comment: this line sir,         Integer checkedID = userCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

Comment: Post your XML details too.

Comment: Already edit it in my question :)

Comment: I have tested your code you need to set checked one of the RadioButton in your XML using android:checked="true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
Integer checkedID = userCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

here, `userCategory`is a RadioButton. Use this:

```
Integer checkedID = (enter here your RadioGroupId).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check who is logged in and just make you one NavigationDrawer invisible for user and the second one visible.
    For example, you check userCategory and if it is parent you make Navigation Drawer for teachers invisible

```
final RadioGroup userCategory = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.user_radio_group_btn);
    userCategory.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            Integer checkedID = userCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = userCategory.findViewById(checkedID);
            int radioId =  userCategory.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) userCategory.getChildAt(radioId);
            String selection = (String) btn.getText();
            if(selection.equals("Parents")){
               menuRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               tuitionProvider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    menuLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    parents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code you need to set checked one of the RadioButton in your XML using ***android:checked="true"***.

You need to set at least one RadioButton checked like

> android:checked="true"

.

Like :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/user_radio_group_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/parents_radio_button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Parents" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tuition_provider_radio_button"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Tuition Provider" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: how bout the java coding sir?

Comment: Your java code is perfect. So you dont need to change it.

Comment: is it the latest coding sir? Because just now I already change it :'( :'(

Comment: Sir, if in my home.xml dont have any Button. But can I write Button coding in my home.java?

Comment: RadioGroup userCategory = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.user_radio_group_btn);
        Integer checkedID = userCategory.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedID);
        String selection = radioButton.getText().toString();

        if (selection.equals("Parents"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Parents", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (selection.equals("Tuition Provider"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tuition Provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: I just want to try. Earlier I tried coding from sir Valgaal. But before I try, all my radio buttons are in Registration.xml. So can I write coding you gave me just now in home.java (which in home.xml dont have any radio button)?

Comment: Okay sir, I already paste the coding in my Registration.java. No error and my apps didnt crash but the navigation for both left and right clickable.

Comment: @Adda I if your application is not crashing then what now what is your problem?

Comment: Both navigation left and right can be clickable. Like I want, if user is parents so, only left navigation can be clickable.

Comment: @Adda so you just need to setup your logic in your code and it will work for you.